# Development of a module joomla

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, mootools

I'm trying to develop a simple module using jquery, but I want disable mootools.
I try to use this code in  default.php file

```
 $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    if ($user->get('guest') == 1) {
    $headerstuff = $this->getHeadData();
    $headerstuff['scripts'] = array();
    $this->setHeadData($headerstuff); }

    <jdoc:include type="head" />
```

but i get this error :Using $this when not in object context....

I wait for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are doing is a good idea. If you want to use jQuery, then include it in the noconflict mode, and use `jQuery` instead of `$` to reference it.

But, in any case, this is the code you wanted. `$this` was supposed to be a `JDocument` object, so you need to get it first.

```
 $user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->get('guest') == 1) {
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $headerstuff = $doc->getHeadData();
    $headerstuff['scripts'] = array();
    $doc->setHeadData($headerstuff);
}
```

Comment: I agreee... it's not a good idea to disable Mootools. There are some default extensions that are using it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to edit html document property. You get error because setHeadData() is a method of some Joomla class. You can't use $this outside of class.

Try to get document object and call setHeadData like this:

```
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->setHeadData($headerstuff);
```

Anyway, you can use jQuery and mootools at the same time. Just follow this article: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools

Comment: Why are you still dragging the & with you?

Comment: @ValentinDespa Here's explanation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php#56820

Comment: @Sirtarius - the & operator I believe has deprecated since PHP 5.3